# How and why is a magnetic field transmitted with alternating current?

Tags: motor, ac, basic

I apologize for the basic question (or if it is incorrect in its assumptions,) but how does one account for magnetism in alternating current?

If I generate alternating current to a motor, why do my coil poles become magnetized, and why does the magnetic field rotate?

Looking at a graph of an AC waveform, can the magnetic properties be visually determined?

[image: AC Waveform]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, a point about the title of your question.

You initially ask why it is that a magnetic field is "transmitted" with alternating current.  In terms of transmission, electromagnetic radiation only occurs where a circuit has (or becomes) an antenna.  Otherwise, only an electromagnetic field is generated around the conductors.  This is called a "near-field" and it is not 'transmitted'.

With regard to magnetic fields, a magnetic field is generated when a current flows through a wire.  This current can be D.C. too - the phenomena is not limited to A.C. current.  The direction of the magnetic field depends upon the direction of current flow.  Therefore, if you connect a D.C. source a magnetic field is generated with a constant polarity.  If you connect an A.C. source the magnetic field alternates in polarity.

It is interesting to note that a magnetic field is only measured or observed when a charge moves relative to *you* as an observer.  It is a relative property! If you were able to move down the wire *with* the charge (or alongside the wire at the same speed as the charge), so that the charge is no longer moving relative to you, you would see that the magnetic field disappears completely!
The electric and magnetic fields are related in a peculiar way, similar in some sense as to space and time in that they are relative properties and depend entirely upon the observer.

Here's a really good book which I think you would enjoy:

[http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Electromagnetics_Explained.html?id=MLzPNpJQz9UC&redir_esc=y][1]

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields are generated by electric currents.  Alternating curents will produce alternating magnetic fields, so the waveform of the current really only tells you how the field strength of the magnetic field will vary with time, it says nothing about rotation with more information.

There are several different types of motors.  I am not really an expert on motors, but most industrial motors are 3 phase AC motors.  This means they are powered by three different AC waveforms of the same frequency that are 120 degrees out of phase.  Basically, this means that when one phase is at a maximum, one of the others is increasing and the other is decreasing.  If you build 3 electromagnets and arrange them radially about a point, then you can create a rotating magnetic field in between them.  If you then stick a permanent magnet in there, it will spin at 3600 RPM (1 revolution per cycle, assuming 60 Hz AC).

Other types of motors use the magnetic fields to create eddy currents.  The eddy currents create opposing magnetic fields which interact with the externally applied field to create a torque on the shaft.  It's not possible to create eddy curents without a time-varying magnetic field, so these motors require AC to run.

DC motors use a commutator to generate AC internally.  The rotor contains coils of wire which are connected to the commutator so that the coils generate magnetic fields of different polarities depending on the shaft angle.  The time-varying magnetic fields produced by the spinning rotor are precisely timed to interact with the stator magnets to generate torque.  In this case, the timing is determined mechanically by the commutator and not electricaly by the applied waveform.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question
So a changing current has a varying Electric field and since the electric field is varying it generates a magnetic field. This is basically best understood if you review Faraday and Ampere-Maxwell Laws of Electromagnetics.

Here is a link for how the motor works hope this helps.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/indmot.html#c1

Answer (score -2):

This can be a funky concept, so it's quite possible the the solution I understand is... not perfect.

**Magnetic fields** are found in things like Horse shoes magnets, and are called the H-field: HERE is where it starts at North pole, HERE is where it ends at south pole.
[image: h-field]
**Electric fields** form when current moves through a wire. Called the E-field, these ELECTRIC fields go for EVER or form a circle.

[image: e-field]
E-fields are good, H-fields are... not so good.

Oh, they both do a good enough job in a motor (I may be corrected on this point): push a current through a wire in a field, it moves. The problems are in that word "magnetised".
If you have a big enough electric field, the E-field can saturate, and energy gets stored in the H-field. You have created a permanent magnet.

When your motor spins around, and you want to put in some more oomph, you now have to add EXTRA to overcome that pesky H-field which is now pointing in the wrong direction.

**Edit:** I've been marked down, and rather rapidly too. I suspected this would happen: it's a complex issue and even Wikipedia throws a lot of math at you.

Comment: No, current flowing through a wire creates a magnetic field that curls around the wire.  A horeshoe magnet also has a magnetic field that connects the ends of the magent together through te body of the magnet - if you cut it in half, you get two smaller magnets.  An electric field is what you get betwen the plates in a capacitor.  Inside a motor, eletric potential (voltage) pushes current to create magnetic fields, which do all of the work.

Comment: How can H fields be regarded as "not so good". Without H fields, light would not travel through space from the sun and reach us.

Comment: @andy aka: as I mentioned, energy that goes into the h-field is effectively "lost". When creating a field of alternating polarity, the need to use extra energy to overcome the h-field is called "hysteresis". see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_hysteresis

Comment: @AlanCampbell, that's very confusing.  Certainly hysteresis leads to energy loss.  But that is a property of the magnetic material and not magnetic fields in general.  There's energy stored in the magnetic field of a coil.  That energy is not lost, but can be used to do work... like charge up a cap in a resonant circuit.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold yes - it is confusing. The Wikipedia article on Maxwell's Equations is an ocean of math. However, some nuggets of wisdom can be found: a changing electric field creates a magnetic field, and a changing magnetic field creates an electric field. Coils in air act differently to coils in steel or ferrite - but the original question was concerned with "motors".